# PHP - compare Arrays

Tags: php, mysql

I have a website with events, I got two important tables, one with all adresses for the first Newsletter and one for the registered users.

Now I want to send a Reminder to all adresses who doesn't register.

My idea is to compare the E-Mail Adresses from both tables (`tbl_adresses` and `tbl_registered_usr`) and "remove" all E-Mail Adresses which are in both tables.

My code looks like:

```
// Read records
$query = "SELECT email FROM wf_anlaesse WHERE anlaesseID = '$Datum'"; 
$query = mysql_query($query);

// Put them in array
for($i = 0; $array[$i] = mysql_fetch_assoc($query); $i++) ;

// Delete last empty one
array_pop($array);

print_r ($array);

echo "<br /><br /><br /><br />";

// Read records
$query2 = "SELECT email FROM wf_adressen"; 
$query2 = mysql_query($query2);

// Put them in array
for($i = 0; $array2[$i] = mysql_fetch_assoc($query2); $i++) ;

// Delete last empty one
array_pop($array2);

print_r ($array2);


echo "<br /><br /><br /><br />";    
$result = array_diff($array, $array2);
print_r($result);
```

My output is like this:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( [email] => E-MAIL ) 
    [1] => Array ( [email] => E-MAIL ) 
    [2] => Array ( [email] => E-MAIL ) 
    [3] => Array ( [email] => E-MAIL ) ... and so on


Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( [email] => E-MAIL ) 
    [1] => Array ( [email] => E-MAIL ) 
    [2] => Array ( [email] => E-MAIL ) 
    [3] => Array ( [email] => E-MAIL )`... and so on

Array ( )
```

The `array_diff` doesn't do the trick.

Any ideas?

Thanks!
Chris

Comment: Be very careful when writing SQL interfacing code and be sure to read up on [proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php) to avoid severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). As a note, `mysql_query` should not be used in new applications. It's a deprecated interface that's being removed from future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and will make your database code easier to get right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks to me like you want a left join, which gets all of the values in the first (left) table which match the condition. Using `IS NULL` you can specify values which aren't present in the second (right) table.

```
SELECT A.email
FROM wf_adressen A
LEFT JOIN wf_anlaesse B
ON A.email = B.email
WHERE B.email IS NULL
```

This will return all the emails in wf_adressen that do not appear in wf_anlaesse.

Here's an example using PostgreSQL:

```
CREATE TABLE wf_anlaesse (id SERIAL, email TEXT);
CREATE TABLE wf_adressen (id SERIAL, email TEXT, name TEXT);

INSERT INTO wf_adressen VALUES (DEFAULT, 'nikm@nikm.nikm', 'Nik M');
INSERT INTO wf_adressen VALUES (DEFAULT, 'nigelj@nigelj.com', 'Nigel J');

INSERT INTO wf_anlaesse VALUES (DEFAULT, 'nikm@nikm.nikm'); -- only Nik's received it

SELECT A.email
FROM wf_adressen A
LEFT JOIN wf_anlaesse B
ON A.email = B.email
WHERE B.email IS NULL;

       email
-------------------
 nigelj@nigelj.com
```

While MySQL may or may not be different around creating the tables and inserting the values, I'm sure the join syntax is exactly the same.

Comment: Hi Nik Thanks for the reply! Sorry for my late response. This solution works, but I need one tiny change. I need 2 WHERE-Clauses, WHERE B.email IS NULL AND B.anlaesseID = '$ID'. With this second WHERE it shows me nothing, it's blank. Isn't it possible to have Multiple WHERE-Clauses in an JOIN? Or where is my thinking problem? Thanks Chris

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($array as $val){
    foreach($array2 as $key => $val2){
    if($val["email"] == $val2["email"])
    unset($array2[$key]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
$result = array_diff($array, $array2);
```

with:

```
$result = array_intersect($array, $array2);
```

regards!